# %[length][type variable] in C#

Tags: c#

In C we can use %7d for example to set the minimum length for the data on console. How can I do this in C#?

Forgive my English, I'm still learning.

Comment: Take a look on [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Alex Thanks a lot. You're a life savior.

Comment: There is no way to limit the text entered into ReadLine. As the MSDN article explains: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx

Comment: @vishwaratna, minimum length would imply *output* (printf) rather than input (scanf). With the latter, "%7d" would be specifying a *maximum* size.

Comment: @paxdiablo , i just saw it. clearly in OP it was not mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Since `"%7d"` controlling *minimum* width is an output operation (with `scanf` *input,* it would be specifying a *maximum* width), [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) is the usual way to get `printf`-style formatting in C#.

For the particular case of "%7d", you could use something like:

```
String.Format("{0,7}", someInt).
```

The link above shows the rather *vast* number of options (and different data types) you can use for formatted output.